# Error in local mongo Connection, working in Vercel in production environment thought

Tags: mongodb, next.js, mongodb-query, vercel, next.js13

I'm having an issue where my MongoDB database connects successfully in production, but fails to connect in localhost. Here's my setup:

**Backend (lib/mongodb.js):**

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // If `globalWithMongo` is not already defined, initialize it as an object
  if (typeof global.globalWithMongo === 'undefined') {
    global.globalWithMongo = {};
  }

  // Use the `globalWithMongo` object to store the `_mongoClientPromise`
  if (!global.globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global.globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global.globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

**Frontend:**

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import clientPromise from "../lib/mongodb";

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  try {
    await clientPromise;
    return {
      props: { isConnected: true },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return {
      props: { isConnected: false },
    };
  }
};

export default function Home({ isConnected }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        {/* Content here */}
        {console.log(isConnected)}
        <h1>We are in mongo Db vercel page</h1>
        <div>
          {isConnected ? (
            <div style={{ color: "green" }}>You are connected to MongoDB!</div>
          ) : (
            <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
              You are not connected to MongoDB.
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I followed an official MongoDB tutorial video (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIlYroSsInU&t=8s) and created a sample Next.js app with MongoDB. However, my implementation only works via Vercel and not on localhost.

I suspect the issue might be with how I'm handling the MongoDB connection in development mode within `lib/mongodb.js`. But I'm not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I owe you my gratitude.
your code in the question resolved my issue in mongodb.js
but here is a small code snippet which can help you temporarily.

I changed my mongodb.js file to this content and it worked but although ill not recommend this as it solves the problems are surface level.

```
 import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
 throw new Error('"Invalid/Missing environment variable:"MONGODB_URI"');
 }
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
//In development mode , use a global variable so that the value
// is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR(Hot Module 
 Replacement).

 client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
 clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

for more info please check docs as this is a temporary solution , but as far as i concern this should work for you as well as code direcly connect with
MongoClient instead of intermediate instance.

[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIlYroSsInU&t=8s)